# Using ncurses library along with standard I/O in C++

Tags: c++, ncurses

I am making a text based Tetris game in C++, to handle the key presses I am making use of the ncurses library function `kbhit()`. However, the library does not work well with the standard I/O like `std::cout`.

I only require the `kbhit()` function, is it possible to use this function along with the standard I/O ?

Edit 1:
on using ncurses and std::cout together, I get an output like this
[image]

**Without ncurses**

[image]

Edit 2:
My question is how to use the standard I/O alongside ncurses and not how to use `kbhit()` and `getch()`

Comment: _"However, the library does not work well with the standard I/O like `std::cout`."_ Could you please elaborate about this?

Comment: Added images to explain it better.

Comment: I think what you need can be found in the answers of the duplicate I linked.

Comment: I am doing the exact same thing, but instead of using printw() I am using the standard I/O. But, using ncurses generates additional spaces at every line.